# TextBox width dynamic adjustment fabric js

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to modify to the textbox width according to the longest line that user enters, dynamically. I initialize the width = width of my canvas but as soon as user exits editing, the width must shorten to the width of the longest line in user's text written in the textBox.

```
obj.on(("editing:exited"),function()  {
    can.setActiveObject(textBox);
    var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, can.getActiveObject().__lineWidths); 
    can.getActiveObject().set("width",largest);

})
```

Problem is that each time I exit editing, the width reduces and the top line is shifted below. I just cant understand what is happening. Please help at the earliest. Thanks in advance. Please also upload a demo so that I can see the effect of your code.

Update 1 : If I change the line

```
    can.getActiveObject().set("width",largest);
```

to

```
    can.getActiveObject().set("width",(largest + 1));
```

It works as desired. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Perhaps you can "uploading a demo" of the problem to get us started.  Thanks and please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question by some coding myself.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpntggdo/8/

To all those who might be facing a similar issue, here is the fiddle and here is the code.

```
textBox.on(("changed"),function(){
       var actualWidth = textBox.scaleX * textBox.width;
        var largest = canvas.getActiveObject().__lineWidths[0];
        var tryWidth = (largest + 15) * textBox.scaleX;
        canvas.getActiveObject().set("width",tryWidth);
        if((textBox.left + actualWidth) >= canvas.width - 10)
         {
             textBox.set("width", canvas.width - left - 10)
        }
            canvas.renderAll();

    });

    textBox.on(("modified"),function(){
      left = textBox.left;
      canvas.renderAll();

    });
```